# bash script to sed replace image numbers with variable count

Tags: html, bash, shell, sed

I have an html document with 200 images. The html page right now just has all of the images named g001.jpg. The image names are g001.jpg through g200.jpg in the image directory.  I need to replace the names g001.jpg with g002.jpg, g002.jpg, g004.jpg etc. I have been trying to do that with bash. Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {001..200}

do
sed "s/g001.jpg/g$i.jpg/g" gallery2.html > gallery3.html

done
```

**To be clear I am trying to rename the references to the image file names within the html document. The html document doesn't need to be renamed.

This of course renames them to g1.jpg a bunch of times then restarts with g2.jpg a bunch of times then g3.jpg a bunch of times and so on until I get g200.jpg a bunch of times. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few issues here. If you use sed like that it will replace each & every occurrence of `g001.jpg` instead of the very first instance. Also you wanted to replace `g001.jpg with g002.jpg, g002.jpg, g004.jpg` so you need to start loop with number 2. Following code should work for you:

```
for l in {2..200}
do
   i=$(printf "%03d" $l)
   sed -i.bak "1,/g001\.jpg/{s/g001\.jpg/g${i}.jpg/g;}" gallery2.html
done
```

Note that because of `-i` flag above sed will do inline editing and save replaced file in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Just incorporate the loop variable into the output file name. 
Note gallery$i_new.html is my naming...

```
for i in {001..200}
do
   sed "s/g001.jpg/g$i.jpg/g" gallery$i.html > gallery$i_new.html
done
```

Comment: Sometimes it is better to write `${i}_new.html` in order to avoid the interpreter to think `i_new` is the name of the variable.

Comment: Thanks, but this renames the html document. I just need to rename the reference to the image file names within the html document and produce a new html document (i.e. gallery3.html).

Comment: @fedorqui I was under the impression that a one char length variable was guaranteed to parse correctly without {}.

Comment: I don't think so, @suspectus. I just tried `for i in {1..5}; do echo $i_t; done` and did not work. It may work in some environments, but it is safer to wrap with `{}`.

Comment: @jason can you give an example of the ing reference from the html file?

Comment: @fedorqui - interesting. Was your test on linux?